# Inversion bracket with long text in Latex

Tags: math-mode, cases, text

How can you write following equation in Latex. Basically I have faced problem with long text
[image]

I used

```
\begin{equation}

  \max\limits_{x,\lambda,\nu} L_(x,\lambda,\nu=\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}

    f(x), & \text{if}\text{if x satisfy the primal condition} \\
    \infty, & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}\right.

\end{equation}
```

I got

[image]

Comment: you presumably got an error message that `\text` is undefined. After (any) error message the pdf output is not usable, and you should ask about the error not show the output. (load the `amsmath` package to define it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `cases*` environment from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ \theta_{\mathcal{P}}(w) = \begin{cases*}
f(w) & if $w$ satisfies primal constraints \\
0 & otherwise
  \end{cases*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Please note that questions like this is generally frowned upon here as it has the characteristics of a `do this for me` question. Generally you should show what you have do far. Any good latex instructions should tell you how to construction expressions like this.

```
\theta_{\mathcal{P}}(w) = 
 \begin{cases} 
   f(w) & \text{if $w$ ... } 
       \\ 
   \infty & \text{otherwise} 
 \end{cases}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want, a day, to use the enviroment `array` instead of the best specific environment `cases` or `dcases`, you can to use this MWE.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\theta_{\mathcal{P}}(w) = \left\lbrace
\begin{array}{ll}
f(w) & \text{if $w$ satisfy the primal condition}\\
\infty & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```